# Cómo simplificar la validación

Tags: javascript

He estoy creando un código que obtiene el campo1 y el campo 2 y funciona correctamente, pero quiero evitar que se deje vació esos campos pero me produce el error "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined".

He estado probando de diversas maneras pero no doy con la solución y debe ser algún mínimo detalle, al igual que no consigo evitar dejar los campos vacíos.

Así es funcional.

```js
var mensaje = "!referencia campo1 campo2"
var campo1 = mensaje.split(" "), campo2 = campo1[0].length+campo1[1].length+2;
if(!campo1)return console.log("!Referencia no puede estar vacio, debes completar el campo1 y campo2.");
console.log(campo1[1])
console.log(mensaje.slice(campo2))
```

```js
var mensaje = "!referencia"
var campo1 = mensaje.split(" "), campo2 = campo1[0].length+campo1[1].length+2;
if(!campo1)return console.log("!Referencia no puede estar vacio, debes completar el campo1 y campo2.");
console.log(campo1[1])
console.log(mensaje.slice(campo2))
```

Estando los campos vacíos, me devuelve el error y no me verifica que estén vacíos.

var campo1 = mensaje.split(" "), campo2 = campo1[0].length+campo1[1].length+2;
                                                                    ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

---

Lo he solucionado definiendo campo y cambiándolo de posición la condición, no sé si sea una forma correcta pero si me podéis indicar una mejor forma de hacerlo os lo agradecería.

```js
var campo1 = mensaje.split(" "); if(!campo1[1]) return; var campo2 = campo1[0].length+campo1[1].length+2; if(!campo1[2]) return;
```

Comment: Si estás tratando de hacer obligatorios algunos inputs de tu form, ¿no bastaría con colocarles el atributo **`required`**?

Comment: @BetaM no es para un form si no esa sería la opción, el problema es que se me escapa algo a la hora de filtrar con length que se queda vació y quiere que le retorne algún valor según entiendo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probando el último código, el que te da el error. Estás intentando recuperar el length de una posición que no existe. Si entras en la posición campo1[0] tienes el mensaje "!referencia" y en la posición campo1[1] no tienes nada y al ejecutar .length de nada produce el error.

Lo que podrías hacer es comprobar antes si existen las dos posiciones para realizar la suma:

```
var mensaje = "!referencia"
var campo1 = mensaje.split(" ");
if(campo1.legth >= 2) {
  campo2 = campo1[0].length+campo1[1].length+2;
  //O las posiciones que quieras    
} else {
  console.log("!Referencia no puede estar vacio, debes completar el campo1 y 
    campo2.");
  return
}
```

En el caso de recuperar la variable de algún formulario o de un campo y lo quieres es comprobar que no estén vacíos podrías hacer lo siguiente.

```
    var mensaje = "!referencia campo2"
    var campos = mensaje.split(" "); 
    if(!campos[1] || !campos[2]) {
        return console.log("!Referencia no puede estar vacio, debes completar el campo1 y campo2.");
    }

    //O bien usando dos variables. De forma que queda mas claro
    var input1 = "!referencia"
    var input2 = "!referencia2"
    if(!input1 || !input2) {
        return console.log("!Referencia no puede estar vacio, debes completar el campo1 y campo2.");
    }
```

Yo usaría el ".length" para comprobar que un campo concreto tiene un longitud mínima para la validación. Como podría ser un campo nombre, o descripción o referencia.

```
    var campo1 = "!referencia"
    var campo2 = "!referencia2"
    var producto = "A2017800913"
    //Si alguno de los dos campos está vacío
    if(!campo1 || !campo2) {
        return console.log("!Referencia no puede estar vacio, debes completar el campo1 y campo2.");
    }
    //Validas que no esté vacío y que además sea más grande o igual a 12
    if((!producto || producto.length >= 12)) {
        return console.log("!producto no puede estar vacio o no tiene la longitud necesaria");
    }
```

Comment: De este modo al introducir el otro campo regresaba el error, he orientado el código de otra manera y hasta el momento se ha solucionado si puedes ayudarme a mejorarlo te lo agradecería.

Comment: Has de seleccionar la respuesta como válida. Es la flechita superior. Ahora añado la segunda manera como lo haría yo si en teoria se supone que la recuperas de algún campo o de un formulario.

Comment: Lo que sucede es que obtengo la información de mensaje por eso que no lo tenga la información por separado ya que la extraigo de un mismo campo y utilizado el array para extraer los datos por separado pero básicamente me daba error al llamar antes declararlo, pero lo doy por solucionado.